# How do I delete an embedded document image in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, carrierwave, rails-admin

I am currently using Mongoid, CarrierWave and rails_admin.

And for some reason when I try to delete an image from an embedded document, it never gets deleted.  Any ideas what I can try?  Here are my models:

```
class Quiz
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :rewards, cascade_callbacks: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rewards
end


class Reward
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :quiz

  field :tagline,           type: String
  field :description,       type: String

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

I have seen the bug from 3 years ago, but still can't resolve this issue?:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/81

Comment: Do you have the Moped logs?

Comment: It's actually mongoid, and the system is sending in an attribute that says remove_picture=>"1"

Answer (score 2):

In case if anyone still looking for the answer

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :rewards, allow_destroy: true
```